# javascript bind events issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to check with you guys/gals if I'm writing this correctly. What I'm trying to do is listen for when the user 'pause' / 'complete' the video. The 1st video runs the complete() and pause() properly and it outputs correctly in the console log but when I tested out the 2nd video, complete() and pause() doesn't show anything in the console log. I'm wondering if it's because I have (2) bind functions that's causing the issue. If anyone can please help me out or how to write this better, I'd be greatly appreciated.

```
( function(window, document, $, undefined) {

     function complete(){
         // do something here
         console.log('video completed');
     }

     function pause(){
         // do something here
         console.log('video paused');
     }

     // 1st video
     $('.short .player').bind({
         ready: function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // do something here
             complete();
             pause();
         }
     });

     // 2nd video
     $('.long .player').bind({
         ready: function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // do something here
             complete();
             pause();
         }
     });

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

///////////////////////  UPDATED ONE /////////////////////////

```
( function(window, document, $, undefined) {

     function complete(){
         // do something here
         console.log('video completed');
     }

     function pause(){
         // do something here
         console.log('video paused');
     }

     // 1st video
     $('.short .player').one({
         click: function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // do something here
             complete();
             pause();
         }
     });

     // 2nd video
     $('.long .player').one({
         click: function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // do something here
             complete();
             pause();
         }
     });

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: No, having two bind functions has nothing to do with it. The `ready` event you're binding to though might be causing a problem. jQuery has a special case in place that redirects that to `$(document).ready`, therefore it isn't really listening for the video to be ready at all.

Comment: I decided to use the ready event because I only want to know 'once' when the user clicks (play) the video. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: The first video reads the done() and pause(). The second video doesn't read it. 

Thanks for trying to help, I'll keep hammering on this and hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: I jus tknow that the ready event likely isn't what you need. Why one is triggering and not the other though is strange... if what i suspected is the case, they both would have been triggered.

Comment: UPDATE: Instead of using the .bind(), I've changed it to the .one() with a click function. That seems more reasonable to use since I only want to hear the user click once on the video so I know when they watched it but the 2 functions( pause(), complete() ) are still not running in the 2nd video.

Comment: Both videos exist in your page when it loads?

Comment: Both exist in my page.

Comment: I agree with Kevin, the `ready` event is not what you are looking for. Do you use the `<video>` tag for the player? Then you can take a look at the [available events](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#Media_Events).

Comment: Is the second video actually loading? Can you provide the html of your document?

Comment: I'm going to hammer on this for a bit and then I'll get back to you guys. Thank you everyone.